# Laplace transform in ODE

Tags: laplace-transform

Use any method to find the laplace transform of coshbt

Looking to get help with this example for my exam review

Comment: …"any method" eh? I choose table :) http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf

Comment: Lol yes I wish so

Comment: …on a more serious note, you could use the definition of cosh: $cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$, take Laplace transforms of the exponentials (that should be doable by hand), and sum them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The laplace transformations of $coshbt$ is the following
$$\int_0^\infty cosh({bt})e^{-st} dt$$
$$= \int_0^\infty \frac{(e^bt + e^{-bt})e^{-st}}{2} dt$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty e^{-st + bt} + e^{-st - bt} dt $$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty e^{(-s + b)t} + e^{(-s - b)t} dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} \frac {e^{(-s+ b)t}}{-s+b} + \frac{e^{-st - bt}}{-s-b} \end{bmatrix}^\infty_0$$

You can probably take it from here.

Comment: Okay awesome so I just need to integrate that now?

Comment: And then plug in infinity and then minus it from plugging in 0(both for t)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I was unaware the definition of cosh but now it seems straight forward  thanks

Comment: You should've probably been taught that if you're doing Laplace Transformations but your welcome anyways. If it is any help using the definition of sin and cos as complex exponentials is helpful when deriving their Laplace transformation.

Comment: I got a final answer of s/s^2-b^2 is that CORRECT?

Comment: And yes I was taught it I just missed a class on the intro of laplace transform and I learned inverses first

Comment: @javahelper123 If your final answer is $s/(s^2-b^2)$, then yes, you are correct (you can compare to the table I linked to above).